# Detecting a key press in a text box and receiving an overload EventHandler error message

Tags: c#, textbox, event-handling, keypress, onkeydown

I am requiring some assistance with my C# program, where I am getting an error message for having a form where the user would enter in text into a text box.  I am trying to detect if the user has pressed the Enter key, and on doing so would produce a message box with a message.  However, I am trying to call the "KeyEventArgs" class which would allow me to detect the key press, but receive the following error message:

**No overload for 'TextBox_KeyDown' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'**

Here is my code for the TextBox I am using:

```
    private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You have entered the correct key.");
        }
    }
```

Clicking on the error message for further details, leads me to the Designer class for the form I am using, and underlines the following text:

```
   this.TextBox.KeyDown += new System.EventHandler(this.TextBox_KeyDown);
```

Comment: maybe use the `KeyPressEventArgs`

Comment: have you tried changing this line `if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)` to this `if (e.KeyCodes == Keys.Enter)` and I would think that would be the `KeyPress_Event` instead

Answer (score 2):

Use the `KeyEventHandler` instead. Also, is the name of your `TextBox` actually `TextBox`? This isn't recommended as it becomes ambiguous as to whether you're referring to an instance or the TextBox control object.

```
 this.TextBox.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(this.TextBox_KeyDown)
```

Your error message refers to the fact that your method's signature is `(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)` but the delegate you're trying to pass actually has a signature of `` `(object sender, EventArgs e) ``.

Answer (score 0):

try
this.TextBox.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.TextBox_KeyDown);